# How can i toggle the awesome wm in total fullscreen

Tags: functional-programming, window, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using the awesome wm and i want every window to be to the edge of my monitor without any taskbars or title bars.
Is there a way to do this?
I'm on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this should be easy. Simply add the line

```
fullscreen = true,
```

to your awesome rules.

Your rules would look afterwards something like this:

```
awful.rules.rules = {
-- All clients will match this rule.
{ rule = { },
  properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width,
                 border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                 focus = awful.client.focus.filter,
                 fullscreen = true,
                 raise = true,
                 keys = clientkeys,
                 buttons = clientbuttons,
                 screen = awful.screen.preferred,
                 placement = awful.placement.no_overlap+awful.placement.no_offscreen
 }
},
```

The taskbar would be still there but it would be hidden behind the fullscreen window.

cheers